# Php background process using proc_open

Tags: php, cmd, exe, proc-open

I would like to open a process with

```
"Start /b".$cmd
```

and still have the ability to check its status (.i.e running?)
Is it possible?

When I try to use

```
proc_open ( "Start /b".$cmd , $descriptorspec , $pipes )
```

and check the

```
proc_get_status($process)['running']
```

it returns false
although the process is running ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process *created* by `Start` is running - `Start` itself has long stopped running.
Therefore, `proc_get_status($process)['running']` returns false.

Is there a concrete reason you can't use `$cmd` directly as in

```
proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
```

?